# Youtube copyright violation acknowledge notification

Tags: youtube

In my youtube account i have uploaded many videos. After a few days of uploading a third party video i could see a link near the video saying acknowledge this video as it is copyrighted. I click and then there were no trouble. But recently i uploaded few videos and  missed to check it again for a month. When i logged in youtube after than i could see warning from youtube stating that i have violated the copyright of a company and i have only two more changes and then my account will be terminated. I think youtube would had shown a acknowledge link but i missed to acknowledge.

I want to know how to get check whether a video uploaded has a acknowledge notification. Do i have to login youtube each day to see whether the videos uploaded have a acknowledge link? or do youtube send an email stating that i should ack the video before it removes and flags as copyright violated?

Answer (score 3):

These are two different actions taken by YouTube and is not a reflection on your failing to acknowledge anything.

In the first situation, YouTube's algorithms discovered copyrighted content in the video uploaded. The rights holder has instructed YouTube to not take the video down but instead show advertising that promotes the third-party content.  So if you upload a video that includes a clip of a movie or a song from an album, YouTube will display a link to purchase that movie or album in and around your video. By having you acknowledge the content, YouTube now has a record of your agreeing that you uploaded a video with someone else's content but no other action will be taken.

In the second situation, you ran up against a rights holder who isn't willing to have their stuff posted by someone else and has told YouTube to remove all submissions that violate their copyright. YouTube allows you up to three "takedown" strikes before they will terminate your account completely (even if the other 97% of your videos are wholly original).

Note that "strikes" are only counted in the second scenario.  Acknowledging content when prompted by YouTube (your first scenario) does NOT count as a strike against the account.

Comment: oh... i wonder about other users who post many videos from third party and still running their account... may be that the uploaded videos did not fall in the second category... would it be like that? anyway i think i have to choose some other video sharing website. The video i posted is from a regional TV channel discussing about health. Thats a very useful information and will not be telecast again... so thought of having a copy in my youtube.

Comment: Takedowns are rare, but they do happen.  Most of the time it goes as the first scenario...you are notified that you did it but YouTube just adds the ads and no harm is done.  So if you are going to get into the habit of reposting videos that you don't own, get familiar with this process.